# Is Ubuntu within Windows slower than setting up separate partitions?

Tags: partitioning, system-installation, windows, performance, wubi

I have a question about Ubuntu performance within Windows. After acquiring a fairly old laptop to test my websites created on a Mac, and being subjected to endless pause and freezes I decided to load Ubuntu.

This is now my first week using it and I am very happy so far.  Following the forum here and using the terminal, I have solved most of the niggles, WIFI connection issues, etc. and feel I can use this as a netbook.

I want to keep Windows on the laptop, so I installed Ubuntu within Windows using the .exe download. Does this significantly slow Ubuntu down? Should I scratch everything and make a partition? Or for day-to-day mild usage, is it okay as it is?

There are no documents, files, photos, music or videos on the machine -- its existence was simply to test websites, and now with Ubuntu to surf the net and check emails.

Lastly, if I choose to keep the current setup, is it possible to have Ubuntu as the default boot up? Right now, if I turn on the machine and walk away it will load in Windows - I have to sit and wait and then select Ubuntu and hit return.

Answer (score 0):

Since .exe installation creates a single file to run Ubuntu it can reduce the performance comparing to the direct HDD partition. But you won't notice much difference as it's being used to test websites.

When you install Ubuntu with exe it modifies the Windows bootloader so you can simple change with

http://neosmart.net/EasyBCD/

Hope this answered :)